# monitor.enter(lock) issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I am developing a web page in ASP.NET using C#.

Many users can access that page at the same time.

On button click I am calling a function which has a critical section.

I have put that code in

```
try
{
    moniter.enter(lock)         
    salbapi.Sislemcu_Epayroll_Salffs_Bapi(Saljv_str, "N", out messdata, ref Saljv_table);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
finally
{
    moniter.exit(lock).
}
```

Now suppose if 2 users are accessing the function at same time.

The resulting messages of processing gets exchanged or not get exchanged (wrong messages are displayed to user).

It should not happen.

Comment: Are you sure this code is running in a single worker process? If not you can create all the monitors you want but they won't synchronize across processes.

Comment: @kumar if one of the answers is the answer you require it's good form to mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if this is thread-safe? If all threads have visibility of the lock variable, then yes it is.

If one thread has called the method and acquired the lock, another thread coming through will be forced to wait at `Monitor.Enter` until the first thread has called `Monitor.Exit`.

Answer (score 0):

```
lock(Application["Lock"])
{
    salbapi.Sislemcu_Epayroll_Salffs_Bapi(Saljv_str, "N", out messdata, ref     Saljv_table);
}
```

Which ensures that the critical code will only execute once at a time within the application no matter how many simultaneous page requests there are.  I suggest to initialise `Application["Lock"]` in Global.asax on Application_start:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)        
    {
        Application["Lock"] = new object();
    }

    //other handlers
}
```

I also suggest you come up with a better name for the var so that it is clear what it locks and do not reuse it elsewhere for risk of deadlocks.

Comment: i used it but the code inside lock is executing more then once'

Comment: See edit.  You need to use a lock object that is shared between page instances.  Remember each request for the page results in a new instance of the given page class, so a lock variable with class scope will not be shared between requests.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer Tudor is correct.  Long answer:

moniter.enter is a bit low level for this logic.  Try using the lock statement, which is sugar for 'monitor.enter(); try { ... } finally (monitor exit)'.  Also, catching and eating an Exception is very bad form; let the exception bubble up so it is reported.

I would do something like

```
  class Foo
  {
     static object synch = new object();

     void TheMethod()
     {
        lock (synch)
        {
           salbapi.Sislemcu_Epayroll_Salffs_Bapi(...);
        }
     }
```

}

Comment: this will fail in the context of a page event handler because synch is a class level var, we need to use an application level var (or define a singleton, same effect) as per my answer below to meet the requirement.

Comment: @RichardSchneider its working for me but the problem is now when 2 users are accessing this. 2nd user waits till 1st finishes and when when both are done the reults of 1st user are shown to 2nd and vice versa... dont know why this is hapeneing?